# Adding too much information makes your main point less standing out, what is a good phrase for that?

Tags: phrases

I'm a Ph.D student, my adviser always asks me to add more things to my paper. So yesterday, when I argued with him, I was saying "You know, I just think adding too much information can actually make our main point fading out". My adviser said, "what do you mean it is fading out? Do you mean it is too divergent?"

In fact, all I want to say is "Adding too much information makes your main point less standing out", what is the good phrase for that?

Also, is it a correct grammar --- "make it less standing out"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about too much information being a *distraction*, which might be expressed as

> makes your main point **stand out less**.
>   becomes a **distraction to your main point**.

Your original expression

> make it less standing out.

is understandable but not quite correct.

Comment: or detracts from my main point. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the additional information may [clutter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clutter) the paper.

A useful idiom for this purpose is [separate the wheat from the chaff](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/separate-the-wheat-from-the-chaff).